# Problem to properly connect external realm database file in android kotlin project

Tags: database, kotlin, realm

I want to connect an external realm database to my Android project. Realm is already set up in build.gradle. I copied test database file: "realmdata.realm" into "raw" folder in "res".

Running the project gives me the error:

> Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmFileException: Could not resolve the path to the asset file: realmdata.realm Kind: ACCESS_ERROR.
>       ...
>           d.androidrealmtestapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:40)
>       ...

which corresponds to code line:

```
realm = Realm.getInstance(c)
```

No matter if I change filename or position in "res" directory the output is the same. After printing RealmConfiguration the output is: "realmFileName : default.realm" Why "default.realm" since I gave the asset file name: "realmdata.realm"? What am I doing wrong? So my question is how to properly connect an external realm file to the project? I am a beginner in kotlin and realm.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import io.realm.Realm
import io.realm.RealmConfiguration
import io.realm.annotations.RealmModule

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var mainRecycler : RecyclerView
lateinit var text: String
private lateinit var realm : Realm

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    println("--------------------------------------------- ")
    print(application.assets.toString())

    Realm.init(this)

    var c = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
        .assetFile("realmdata.realm")
        .modules(MyModule())
        .readOnly()
        .build()

    println("--------------------------------------------- ")
    println(" c configuration builder file:")
    println(c)
    println("--------------------------------------------- ")

   Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(c)
   realm = Realm.getInstance(c)

   realm.beginTransaction()
    print ("realm ...")
   realm.commitTransaction()

    mainRecycler = findViewById(R.id.main_recycler)
    mainRecycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    mainRecycler.adapter = MainAdapter()

}

@RealmModule(classes = arrayOf(RealmModel::class ))
private class MyModule {}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I copied test database file: "realmdata.realm" into "raw" folder in
>   "res"

You need to copy your database to **`assets`** folder

To create assets folder folow this.
[image]